# Large scale editing to fix national park boundries in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, editing

I recently noticed that OSM does not include the most recently updated versions of the national parks in Utah. I've taken it upon myself to fix this, and I've made up a shapefile from the state governments website. I'm fairly new to OSM editing, but from what I can tell, there isn't really a good tool for really low zoom edits - fixing boundaries this large seems hard.

What is an approach for this?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [JOSM](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/).

You don't have to download the full area which might be just too large in your case. If you know the ID of the boundary relation then go to *File* -> *Download object*, select *relation*, paste the ID and make sure you have selected to *download referrers (parent relations)* and r*elation members*, too.

If you like you can still download additional areas later on via the usual way *File -> Download data*.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I would do this, as someone with an ArcGIS Desktop license, is to use the [ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-editor-for-openstreetmap):

> ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap (OSM Editor) is a free, open-source
>   add-on for ArcMap that helps you take advantage of the OpenStreetMap
>   (OSM) dataset and become an active member of the growing OSM
>   community.

It downloads an area of OpenStreetMap (which can be large) into a file geodatabase, where you can edit it using the editing tools of ArcGIS Desktop, and then post the changes back to OpenStreetMap.

Answer (score 1):

Editing in large volume with every detail possible is done through the Java OpenStreetMap editor or [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/). But since you are updating the old boundaries which have links to other data, editing might cause undesired consequences. Fortunately, the is a group of people who look at such issues and can help and advise you better. Mailing these groups will get you sorted [IMPORTS-US](https://lists.openstreetmap.org/listinfo/imports-us), [TALK-US](https://lists.openstreetmap.org/listinfo/talk-us)